# What is considered a matchmade game in LoL?

Tags: league-of-legends, terminology

So recently (or maybe not recently, I just started playing again) Riot implemented a ["Hextech crafting system"](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/site/2016-season-update/champion-mastery.html). I'm still really confused how it works, but I managed to obtain another box besides the one that they gave me as intro-freebee. Now I think I need a key, but i don't know how to earn one. The article i posted in that link above says:

> Earn keys as rewards for winning any matchmade games or by purchasing them at the store for 125 RP. Keys unlock chests through Hextech Crafting.

But I don't know what a "matchmade" game is officially. [This Q&A](http://forums.na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=1051569) says:

> anything that uses the matchmaking system, so custom games are out, and that's it

but that doesn't help because I still don't know what the matchmaking system is. Aren't all games made by matching? if so, why didn't i receive keys for winning a normal-draft game? And I have RP but whats the point of spending it on this if i can just win it somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matchmade games are any game that is not a custom game, so any game that is played that isn't a custom game can give you a key/keyshard. However, the reason behind you not getting a key/shard is that there is a random chance to get one after a matchmade game, but it doesn't happen every game. I have gotten one about every other game so far, so just play more matches and you will get some.

As of patch 6.6 TT and ARAM are bugged so keys won't drop from them. A fix is planned to be released in the next patch.

Comment: just for completion, does this include ARAM or special game modes?

Comment: @nickson104 if they aren't bot games or custom games then yes

Comment: @Dragonrage although according to the [Patch 6.6 Notes](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/patch/patch-66-notes) *"First off, we'll quickly mention we're aware of a bug where key fragments aren't dropping after matchmade Treeline or ARAM wins. Fixing that is on our list of things that need to be done before we can consider Hextech Crafting fully launched, and we're working on a solution for an upcoming patch."*

Comment: so correction @Dragonrage would be "if they aren't bot games or custom games, then they *should* drop keys, whether or not they actually do"

Comment: @ARadish more like, "if they aren't bot games or custom games, then they can drop keys." though currently TT and ARAM are bugged

Comment: ok, sounds good. although i'm wondering, because i played like six games yesterday and no keys. :/

Comment: @ARadish have you gotten any keyshards? thats all ive gotten so far. but i have gotten enough to craft a few keys

Comment: In the current event 'Forge Destiny', even co-op vs. AI counts as matchmade.

Comment: This is wrong, bot games do count as matchmade games

Comment: @Oak do you have any proof, or are you just claiming that?

Comment: @Dragonrage Not as of now, but it isn't too hard to confirm this, as the Daily Mission where one must win a **matchmade** game is doable on bot games. Note that *Matchmade* differs from *PVP Matchmade* (which would be all PVP modes except for Custom games)

Comment: This is incorrect, co-op (bot) games do count.

Answer (score 1):

A match-made game is any game that is not a custom match, so Co-op (bot) and PvP (normal and ranked).

Also, I think that League re-uses this terminology in two different contexts; the first being for the crafting system and the second being for missions. But, I don't think they mean the same thing in both contexts.

In terms of the crafting context, match-made means "any game that is not a custom game or a bot game" which Dragonrage said, since I don't think I have received a key/key shard from a Co-op (bot) game, but if I'm wrong there, please comment and I'll correct.

In terms of the missions context, match-made means "any game that's not a custom game" since I have had Co-op (bot) games count towards missions which have used this terminology.

Comment: That was already said.

Comment: @FabianRöling You are incorrect, this was not already said. Dragonrage said "Matchmade games are any game that is not a custom game or a bot game, so any game that is played that isn't one of those can give you a key/keyshard." which I did not say since I specified that Co-op (bot) games do count towards matchmade games.