# Do Tutorials or Practice Tools count as a matchmade game?

Tags: league-of-legends

I am trying to get out of low priority and they said I needed to play 5 matchmade games without leaving and I would like to know if Tutorial or Practice tool counts as a matchmade game and I would like to know what does count in a matchmade game.

Comment: AFAIK matchmade is everything where you can't choose the enemies and you can have teammates (IIRC in tutorial you are always alone)

Comment: So is there any examples of where I have to play in

Comment: Ranked, normals, ARAM, random game mode like URF, Co-op (maybe)

Comment: but wait they wouldn't work if I am in low queue priority.

Comment: They work you just have to wait it out. You are supposed to learn something from it and not just skip it by playing easy games. Penalty to those who deserve it (including you!)!

Comment: wait do the twisted treelines count as a normal

Comment: Yes they do. Why should they not?

Comment: but every time I try to go to the normals says to me to leave the queue

Comment: What do you mean with that? And [btw](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/260047/what-is-considered-a-matchmade-game-in-lol?rq=1)

Comment: what I mean is that every time I click find match it always says that I have to leave the queue

Comment: Co-op AI, Normal, Ranked are all matchmade games.